# Autofac Named Registration AggregateServices

Tags: dependency-injection, aggregate, log4net, autofac

I am attempting to refactor some code in an MVC application using Autofac Aggregate services. One of the services I am attempting to inject is an log4net.ILog that is using the type of a specific controller. **edit** 
Per suggestion, I am using the publicly available LoggingModule from the Autofac example on modules. Leaving that out of the question as it's the same as posted:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAggregateService<IHomeControllerDependencies>();
//other service registrations
builder.RegisterModule<LoggingModule>();
builder.RegisterType<HomeController>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());
var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Next, in my aggregate service, I am using the following (leaving out the other services for brevity):

```
public interface IHomeControllerDependencies
{
    ILog Logger { get; }
    //other services
}

public class HomeControllerDependencies : IHomeControllerDependencies
{
    public HomeControllerDependencies(IComponentContext context)
    {
        Logger = context.Resolve<ILog>();
        //other services            
    }

    public ILog Logger { get; }
    //other services
}
```

I then inject the dependencies object in my HomeController as follows:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{    
    private readonly IHomeControllerDependencies _dependencies;

    public HomeController(IHomeControllerDependencies dependencies)
    {
        _dependencies = dependencies;
    }
...
}
```

I still get the error that 'log4net.ILog' has not been registered.
**edit**
The interesting thing here is that when I use the Logger explicitly in the Controller's constructor, and take it out of the aggregate service without modifying registrations, it works and gets the logging instance correctly, even correctly typed as the HomeController Logger:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ILog Logger { get; }

        public HomeController(IHomeControllerDependencies dependencies, ILog logger)
        {
            _dependencies = dependencies;
            Logger = logger;
        }
...
}
```

Aggregate:

```
public interface IHomeControllerDependencies
{
    //other services
}

public class HomeControllerDependencies : IHomeControllerDependencies
{
    public HomeControllerDependencies(IComponentContext context)
    {
        //other services            
    }

    //other services
}
```

I guess I could keep it this way, but the main reason why I'm using aggregate services is to have a one parameter constructor.

Thanks

Comment: You registered your `ILog` as named service and ask for a TypedService. See http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html for help on how to integrate log4net in an autofac application

Comment: I thought that the ResolveName would resolve anything that was set up with that name. I guess I misunderstood what was going on. I'll check out the link you sent. Thanks

Comment: It's not the goal of a named registration. You could also look have a look at this : http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html to better understand named registration :-)

Comment: I feel like I understand what's going on in the Logger module, but I'm unsure how to resolve the Logger from the HomeControllerDependencies class with a resolve command, as my other services are typically resolved. Do either of you know how these modules work with AggregateServices?

Comment: Just as an update, if I put my ILog into the constructor of the Home controller, using the LoggerModule you linked, it works great. However, moving it to the dependencies object it won't resolve and breaks the program as above. I guess I could leave it as a separate injection, but that kinda defeats the whole purpose of using the Aggregate service registration.

Comment: Could you edit your question with your latest attempt?

Comment: Edited, thanks again. Let me know if you see something I'm screwing up.